# Java synchronized object - NullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays, synchronization

I am getting a NullPointerException when running the code below. It appears to be in regards to synchronized(myLocks[inc]). If I am using the array object simply to guard access using each element of the array per thread, why does it need to be initialized to not null? Would I use a for loop in myChildClass? - my attempt did not succeed and I am questioning this.

```
class myChildCLass extends myCLass {
    private Object myLocks[];

    myChildClass(int inc) {
        super(inc);
        myLocks = new Object[inc];
    }
    void count(int inc) {
        synchronized(myLocks[inc]){myArray[inc]++;} 
    }
}
```

Comment: All the objects in your array are null. You first need to assign a value to each element of `myLocks`

Comment: This is a silly question, but how could I do that (assign any value to ALL of them at once within this code)

Comment: Also and more importantly (i will figure out the initialization myself )- why do they need to be initialized to a value. Why is it not enough to already have objects, even if they are null, to use as guards? The object is the guard, its value isn't.

Comment: You don't have objects when the reference is `null`. `null` is not an Object. And you can use a for-loop to initialize your array.

Comment: "You don't have objects when the reference is null." - Interesting. Thank you